# Reducing row count of CROSS JOIN + LEFT JOIN where there is no linkage

Tags: mysql, join, cross-join

I've been struggling with this for quite some time.  I have a [SQLFiddle with the same approximate contents of this question.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c81b1/36)

I have three tables, `items`, `profiles`, and the linking table, `posts` that keys from the former two tables, schema with example data:

```
create table items ( 
  item_id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
  title varchar(255)
);

insert into items (item_id, title) VALUES(1, 'Item One');
insert into items (item_id, title) VALUES(2, 'Item Two');
insert into items (item_id, title) VALUES(3, 'Item Three');
insert into items (item_id, title) VALUES(4, 'Item Four');
insert into items (item_id, title) VALUES(5, 'Item Five');

create table profiles (
  profile_id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
  profile_name varchar(255)
);

insert into profiles (profile_id, profile_name) VALUES(1, 'Bob');
insert into profiles (profile_id, profile_name) VALUES(1, 'Mark');
insert into profiles (profile_id, profile_name) VALUES(1, 'Nancy');

create table posts (
  post_id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
  item_id int unsigned, -- Relates to items.item_id
  profile_id int unsigned, -- Relates to profile.profile_id,
  post_date DATETIME
);

insert into posts (item_id, profile_id, post_date) values(1, 1, NOW());
insert into posts (item_id, profile_id, post_date) values(2, 2, NOW());
insert into posts (item_id, profile_id, post_date) values(2, 2, NOW());
```

I am using the following query to produce nearly-correct results:

```
SELECT 
  `items`.`item_id`,
  `items`.`title`,
  `profiles`.`profile_id`,
  `profiles`.`profile_name`,
  `posts`.`post_id`, 
  `posts`.`post_date`
  FROM `items` 
  CROSS JOIN `profiles`
  LEFT JOIN  `posts` ON `items`.`item_id` = `posts`.`item_id`
    AND `posts`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`profile_id`;
```

For my particular application this is sub-optimal. I get a lot of 'extra' rows that my particular implementation does not need.  The end result looks something like this:

```
+------------|------------|---------|-----------+
| Item Name  | Profile ID | Post ID | Post Date |
+------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| Item One   | 1          | 1       | 2015-...  | -- Bob Posted this
| Item One   | 2          | NULL    | NULL      | -- No one else did
| Item One   | 3          | NULL    | NULL      |
| Item Two   | 1          | 2       | 2015-...  | -- Bob posted this
| Item Two   | 2          | 3       | 2015-...  | -- So did mark
| Item Two   | 3          | NULL    | NULL      | -- Nancy didn't
| Item Three | 1          | NULL    | NULL      | 
| Item Three | 2          | NULL    | NULL      |
| Item Three | 3          | 4       | 2015-...  | -- Only nancy posted #3
| Item Four  | 1          | NULL    | NULL      | -- No one posted #4
| Item Four  | 2          | NULL    | NULL      |
| Item Four  | 3          | NULL    | NULL      | 
| Item Five  | 1          | NULL    | NULL      | -- No one posted #5
| Item Five  | 2          | NULL    | NULL      |
| Item Five  | 3          | NULL    | NULL      | 
+------------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

This is doing exactly as I requested - each item is returned three times (to correspond to the profile count).  However it would be ideal if in the case of Items #4 and #5, where there is NO linkage, that they only be returned one time, with a NULL profile_id, as below:

```
+------------|------------|---------|-----------+
| Item Name  | Profile ID | Post ID | Post Date |
+------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| Item One   | 1          | 1       | 2015-...  | -- Bob Posted this
| Item One   | 2          | NULL    | NULL      | -- No one else did
| Item One   | 3          | NULL    | NULL      |
| Item Two   | 1          | 2       | 2015-...  | -- Bob posted this
| Item Two   | 2          | 3       | 2015-...  | -- So did mark
| Item Two   | 3          | NULL    | NULL      | -- Nancy didn't
| Item Three | 1          | NULL    | NULL      | 
| Item Three | 2          | NULL    | NULL      |
| Item Three | 3          | 4       | 2015-...  | -- Nancy posted #3
| Item Four  | NULL       | NULL    | NULL      | -- **No one posted #3 and #4
| Item Five  | NULL       | NULL    | NULL      | -- Only need #3 and #4 once**
+------------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

While in this example this only translates to 4 less rows, in my real-world application, there are many items, but not many profiles and posts.  So this small change could reduce server-side language processing significantly.

Could anyone point me in the correct direction limit the cross join only where I have some type of linkage?

Comment: Very well written question, with scripts and a fiddle. All do as A.B. Carroll does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  `items`.`item_id`,
        `items`.`title`,
        `profiles`.`profile_id`,
        `profiles`.`profile_name`,
        `posts`.`post_id`, 
        `posts`.`post_date`
FROM    `items` 
LEFT JOIN
        `profiles`
ON      EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    `posts`
        WHERE   `posts`.`item_id` = `items`.`item_id`
        )
LEFT JOIN
        `posts`
ON      `items`.`item_id` = `posts`.`item_id`
        AND `posts`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`profile_id`
ORDER BY
        `items`.`item_id`, `profiles`.`profile_id`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c81b1/41

Comment: I'm really curious how this works, if you could expand on it a little, that would be great, but otherwise, I'm blown away and a sincere thank you!

Comment: @A.B.Carroll: you don't do a cross join to profiles, instead you do a left join with a true or false condition depending only on `items`. This condition is "are there posts on that item"? If there are, the condition is true and all profiles are selected as if with a cross join; if there aren't, the condition is false and a single NULL record is selected from `profiles`. The rest is the same.